# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space after convering project to Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

There are several questions on this topic and I went through all of the answers but I am still having the same problem. I am trying to implement spring security on an existing project that did not use spring previously. I successfully converted to a maven project and added a login form with no problems. I proceeded to make more changes, left for the day, came back the next and tomcat started throwing this error. I tried rolling back the changes I made and nothing made a difference, until I disabled the maven nature of the project. As soon as I did that, the error went away and as soon as I configure as maven project the error returns.

I have tried the following things as suggested in other stack overflow answers:

- adding a _JAVA_OPTIONS -Xmx1024m user variable in environment variables
- adding a MAVEN_OPTS -Xmx1024m user variable in environment variables
- adding -XX:MaxPermSize=128M and -XX:PermSize=128M after -vmargs in the eclipse.ini
- setting Java_OPTS to -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled
- adding -Xmx512m to my POM
- adding -XX:MaxPermSize=512m and -XX:PermSize=512m to my Tomcat launch configuration

Originally Perm Generation was 99% however after adding -XX:PermSize=128M to eclipse.ini it went to a much lower percentage but this problem still persists

Thanks in advance! Any advice at all at this point would be helpful.

[image]

I either get one of two errors which are similar just different stack traces.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at java.lang.Throwable.getStackTraceElement(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Throwable.getOurStackTrace(Throwable.java:591)
    at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:462)
    at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:451)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:450)

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2818)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1148)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1643)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.checkHandlesTypes(ContextConfig.java:1956)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:1919)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1806)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1765)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1751)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1255)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:882)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:317)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5081)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:774)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:620)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Update:
As suggested in the comments this seems to show exactly what the problem is. Perm Gen is shown totally full. What is the difference between this and what jmap (the other picture) is showing?  One says 16MB and full the other says 128MB and room to spare. How do I increase the Perm Gen in this picture?

[image]

[image]

Comment: how do you launch tomcat ?

Comment: I would open up `jvisualvm` and get some more info about where your memory is going

Comment: I launch tomcat through Eclipse and have not really had any problems previously.
@ug_ It seems the Perm Gen size from the visualvm is different from what jmap was telling me. Whatever I did before seemed to increase the jmap number but not the one shown by the visual vm. Any ideas what's going on there?

Comment: Your screenshot's perm gem is point to jvisualvm process rather than your maven process. Can you choose pid 5856 and check on the perm gem?

Comment: Thanks for that, I have added both pictures to the post. As you can see it says I have increased the Perm Gen size and there is free space. However the error still remains. Does maven have a separate Perm Gen space?

Comment: `MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=??` help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are using m2e plugin. If you are using m2e to execute maven proess, it will start a separate jvm. You need to configure VM argument for that process. Refer to screenshot below. You can try with a simple maven project first before apply to your project.

Sample pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

1. Configure maven goal. Make sure select the project workspace and set maven goals correctly. You should use `tomcat7:run` if you are using tomcat7 plugin
   [image: maven goal]
2. Configure VM arguments. Example: -Xmx1024m -Xms1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:PermSize=256m
   [image]
3. Check the JVM argument that you set using JVisualVM. Select the process and get it from overview tab. Sample screenshot as below. 
   [image]

Comment: I am using m2e. I don't know if this is related or not but when I do what you suggested and hit run it gives me an error saying no goals have been specified for this build. I normally do not explicitly tell maven to build my project. The one other time I did I encountered the same error and just launched tomcat like normal and it worked. This time I entered those arguments and both the build failed and tomcat still throws the same error.

Comment: @farnett, no goals have been specified is because you didn't set maven goal properly. I added sample pom.xml and provide more detail steps by steps in the answer. Give it a try.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I added the goal like you said and ran my project, however something very weird occurred. It started running code I did not recognize on the url I specified (it was a spring security example which was not in my project). The only thing I could think of to cause this was a maven dependency. I found one I wasn't using and removed it and now the program is running. However, I don't think I have solved the problem as opposed to just postponing it.  Perhaps deleting that dependency freed up some perm gen space?

Comment: Yes. Less dependencies means less classes loaded. It will reduces usage of perm gem. But did you check the running tomcat have the java opts as configured?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot point to exactly what fixed the problem, it was most likely a combination of things, regardless tomcat seems to now recognize the new PermGen space. Thanks for all the help, I really appreciate it!